# viewController view not loaded

Tags: ios, ios4, core-data

I created a window-based project for iphone; I wanted start with core data.
I added a viewController and I created all the connections (I think correctly!)
When in the delegate, in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions I try to show my view nothing happen; when I start the app it shows only the main window.

The code is:

```
//
//  ProvaCoreDataAppDelegate.h
//  ProvaCoreData
//
//  Created by dvd on 17/06/11.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class CoreDataViewController;

@interface ProvaCoreDataAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    CoreDataViewController *viewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet CoreDataViewController *viewController;

@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;


- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;

@end


//
//  ProvaCoreDataAppDelegate.m
//  ProvaCoreData
//
//  Created by dvd on 17/06/11.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ProvaCoreDataAppDelegate.h"
#import "CoreDataViewController.h"

@implementation ProvaCoreDataAppDelegate


@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;

@synthesize managedObjectContext=__managedObjectContext;

@synthesize managedObjectModel=__managedObjectModel;

@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator=__persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self.window addSubview:self.viewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    [self saveContext];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [window release];
    [__managedObjectContext release];
    [__managedObjectModel release];
    [__persistentStoreCoordinator release];
    [viewController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    /*
     Typically you should set up the Core Data stack here, usually by passing the managed object context to the first view controller.
     self.<#View controller#>.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    */
}

- (void)saveContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil)
    {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error])
        {
            /*
             Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

             abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
             */
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        } 
    }
}

#pragma mark - Core Data stack

/**
 Returns the managed object context for the application.
 If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.
 */
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (__managedObjectContext != nil)
    {
        return __managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil)
    {
        __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [__managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return __managedObjectContext;
}

/**
 Returns the managed object model for the application.
 If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
 */
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (__managedObjectModel != nil)
    {
        return __managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"ProvaCoreData" withExtension:@"momd"];
    __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];    
    return __managedObjectModel;
}

/**
 Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
 If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
 */
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
    {
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"ProvaCoreData.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error])
    {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.

         Typical reasons for an error here include:
         * The persistent store is not accessible;
         * The schema for the persistent store is incompatible with current managed object model.
         Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.


         If the persistent store is not accessible, there is typically something wrong with the file path. Often, a file URL is pointing into the application's resources directory instead of a writeable directory.

         If you encounter schema incompatibility errors during development, you can reduce their frequency by:
         * Simply deleting the existing store:
         [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil]

         * Performing automatic lightweight migration by passing the following dictionary as the options parameter: 
         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

         Lightweight migration will only work for a limited set of schema changes; consult "Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide" for details.

         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

#pragma mark - Application's Documents directory

/**
 Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
 */
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

@end

//
//  CoreDataViewController.h
//  ProvaCoreData
//
//  Created by dvd on 17/06/11.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface CoreDataViewController : UIViewController {

    UIView *view;
    UITextField *nameTF;
    UITextField *addressTF;
    UITextField *phoneTF;
    UILabel *statusLbl;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *view;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *nameTF;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *addressTF;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *phoneTF;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *statusLbl;

- (IBAction)saveData:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)findContact:(id)sender;

@end


//
//  CoreDataViewController.m
//  ProvaCoreData
//
//  Created by dvd on 17/06/11.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "CoreDataViewController.h"


@implementation CoreDataViewController
@synthesize view;
@synthesize nameTF;
@synthesize addressTF;
@synthesize phoneTF;
@synthesize statusLbl;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [view release];
    [nameTF release];
    [addressTF release];
    [phoneTF release];
    [statusLbl release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [view release];
    view = nil;
    [self setNameTF:nil];
    [self setAddressTF:nil];
    [self setPhoneTF:nil];
    [self setStatusLbl:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (IBAction)saveData:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)findContact:(id)sender {
}
@end
```

Comment: Too much code. Please read http://sscce.org/ and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You should double check in IB that your viewController outlet is connected to an actual instance of CoreDataViewController.

Comment: I checked it! In the MainWindow.xib I have a viewController object (CoreDataViewController) and a Delegate object (ProvaCoreDataAppDelegate); for the first there is the connection (Referencing outlet) with the viewController property defined in ProvaCoreDataAppDelegate.h and in the second the connection (Outlet) between its outlet viewController and the CoreDataViewController object

Comment: another hint! The viewDidLoad method of my coreDataViewController object isn't called when the app starts; only the main window is displayed! .. I don't understand why! I tried to compare my project with one generated from View-based template and it seems there are no differences!

Comment: Is the view outlet on your viewController object in the nib connected to the view you're trying to display?  Also, check to make sure that the nib is a part of the target you're building.

Comment: The answer to the first question is positive!But, sorry, how can I see if the nib is in the target?

Comment: In Xcode 4, select the nib, show the rightmost pane if it's not showing already, and look under the File Attributes Inspector.  In the Target Membership group, make sure your current target is checked.